# Python, movimiento automático de objetos

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy haciendo el juego de donkey kong y tengo que conseguir que los barriles se muevan, tengo lo siguiente:

Mi función donde pretendo que los barriles se muevan:

```
def inPlatform(objBarrelsmove):
if objBarrelsmove.y==objFloor1.y-11:
    objBarrelsmove.moveBarrel('right',objFloor1)           
elif objBarrelsmove.y==objFloor2.y-11:
    objBarrelsmove.moveBarrel('left',objFloor2)
elif objBarrelsmove.y==objFloor3.y-11:
    objBarrelsmove.moveBarrel('right',objFloor3)
elif objBarrelsmove.y==objFloor4.y-11:
    objBarrelsmove.moveBarrel('left',objFloor4)           
elif objBarrelsmove.y==objFloor5.y-11:
    objBarrelsmove.moveBarrel('right',objFloor5)            
elif objBarrelsmove.y==objFloor6.y-11:
    objBarrelsmove.moveBarrel('left',objFloor6)
```

Después en mi función update, relacionado con los barriles tengo lo siguiente:

```
for b in barrels:
        inPlatform(b)
```

En la función draw (donde creo mis objetos he hecho lo siguiente):

```
for b in barrels:
    pyxel.blt(b.x, b.y, 0, 34, 105, 13, 11, colkey=0)
```

Abajo en el programa principal he escrito esto:

```
barrels=[]
if len(barrels)<10:
     barrels.append(classes.Barrels(50,60))
```

Para terminar, en mi otro documento, donde tengo las clases, he escrito lo siguiente:

```
class Barrels:
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.__x=x
    self.__y=y

@property
def x(self):
   return self.__x

@property
def y(self):
    return self.__y

def moveBarrel(self, direction,pt):
    print("Movebarrels-----------------------------")
    if direction == 'right':
        self.__x +=1
    elif direction == 'left':
        self.__x -=1
    elif direction == 'down':
        self.__y +=1
```